# Apache - delay over HTTPS but not HTTP

Tags: ssl, performance, apache-2.4, http, https

I have a problem with an Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 (almost default settings), virtual cloud server.

On a medium server load (about 2/3.0 cpu usage and tons of free memory) the time for establishing an HTTPS connection grows up to 5-15 seconds (sometimes more). Here an example curl output, have a look at the time:

```
My-MBP:~ me$ curl --trace-time --trace-ascii - https://domain.tld/some.png
20:44:40.952209 == Info:   Trying 111.111.111.111...
20:45:16.046183 == Info: Connected to domain.tld (111.111.111.111) port 443 (#0)
20:45:32.371816 == Info: TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
20:45:32.371919 == Info: Server certificate: www.domain.tld
20:45:32.371946 == Info: Server certificate: GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
20:45:32.372025 == Info: Server certificate: GlobalSign
20:45:32.372069 => Send header, 125 bytes (0x7d)
0000: GET /some.png HTTP/1.1
003c: Host: domain.tld
0055: User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
006e: Accept: */*
007b: 
20:45:32.538703 <= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
20:45:32.538747 <= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 19:47:34 GMT
20:45:32.538765 <= Recv header, 16 bytes (0x10)
0000: Server: Apache
20:45:32.538778 <= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
20:45:32.538795 <= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: Cache-Control: public
20:45:32.538810 <= Recv header, 42 bytes (0x2a)
0000: ETag: "1234567890"
20:45:32.538827 <= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Expires: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 19:57:34 GMT
20:45:32.538844 <= Recv header, 22 bytes (0x16)
0000: Content-Length: 7159
20:45:32.538860 <= Recv header, 25 bytes (0x19)
0000: Content-Type: image/png
20:45:32.538876 <= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
20:45:32.539541 <= Recv data, 7159 bytes (0x1bf7)
...
```

Also the transfer rate of the file is pretty good, only the time to establish the connection is horrible.

But: The whole request/response for the same file over HTTP works very fast (<100 ms). On times with heavy usage (>3.0) there is sometimes also no problem with HTTP and HTTPS.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
...
  SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
  SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
  SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
  SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512
...
</IfModule>
```

Comment: maybe check if you've got enough entropy `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` - should be at least in the tripple digits

Comment: Maybe reverse DNS lookup is enabled with `HostnameLookups On`?

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't happen on "almost default" installation, so I suggest you contact your hosting company about the issue to see if it's already known and/or they can fix it.

Other things that might be useful in resolving the problem:

1. Output of `openssl speed`
2. Trying if connecting to plain openssl "server" will have the same connection delay issue. You can do that by using the following commands on different consoles:

For the server:
`openssl s_server  -4 -www -accept 444 -cert /etc/ssl/example.com.crt  -key /etc/ssl/example.com.key -verify_return_error -debug`

For the client:
`openssl s_client -debug -connect example.com:444`

You might try to connecting to the https://example.com:444 with your browser too.

3. Checking if you provide the intermediate chain along with the certificate itself.
4. Trying to change the cipher suite used by apache with something like this in mod_ssl.conf:

`SSLHonorCipherOrder On`

`SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXP:!LOW:!RC2:!3DES:!SEED:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM`

5. Checking if other clients of your hosting company have the same problem (try connecting to https on IPs around yours)
6. Checking if using nginx front-end for serving https will solve the problem

Comment: Please have a look at my edit: It should use urandom which should give enough entropy or is it wrong?

Comment: edited to get more info...

Comment: Also try the newly added #2 - connecting openssl to openssl without any other software - should be enough to determine if the problem is in apache or in ssl itself...